# Similar to jsp <logic:iterate> in XSL

Tags: html, jsp, struts

I want to use this kind of jsp logic in XSL

```
<logic:iterate name="myForm" id="spec" property="specs">  
  parameter : <html:text name="spec" property="param" indexed="true" />  
  value : <html:text name="spec" property="val" indexed="true" />  
</logic:iterate>
```

is there any way to use `<logic:iterate>` similar to jsp  in XSL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Some example

```
<xsl:for-each select="opportunity">
  <xsl:value-of select="../@id" />
  <xsl:if test="odd/@rate != 100">
    <xsl:value-of select="../@number" />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```